# Convert location.href URL to Anchor link

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview

Exists any JavaScript or Objective-C method to convert a `location.href="MyURL"` to `<a href="MyURL"></a>`??

I have over 200 location.href URL not working with UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked :-S

Thanks to everyone can help me!

Comment: I think you should clarify your question: Do you have an HTML text with links represented as location.href text and you want basic text translation into <a> tags? Please describe the problem in more details so that we can help you

Comment: I want that my Javascript(event){ location.href= http://... } can be read by the browser like an anchor link. 
Is that possible?

Comment: Let's see: so you have this event that basically loads that URL, right? And you want, instead of loading the page, to display the link to that page? In that case you can rewrite your function as ... { document.write("<a href='linkurl'></a>"); } ... that should display the link

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="http://www.myurl.com" id="myAnchor"></a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").setAttribute("href", window.location.href);
        var loc = document.getElementById("myAnchor").getAttribute("href");
        var t = document.createTextNode(loc);
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").appendChild(t);
    </script>
```

Here is one way of doing it: document.getElementById() grabs a reference to the ID attribute of your anchor(s). The second argument of setAttribute(), "window.location.href" grabs a reference to the url in the current window and sets the href attibute in your anchor to this, however if you have a bunch of location.href()s declared in your code, then store these as a variable before the first line instead and then reference that variable at around the same line as where I have declared "loc".  The variable "loc" declares a variable which stores a reference to the newly created href attribute you just declared in the previous line. Then I am declaring a variable "t" which creates a text node in the DOM, with the href from the previous line as the value this variable will hold. Lastly, I use document.getElementById to get "myAnchor" again and append the text node from the previous line to it. So now we can actually see the url in the link.

```
        //Also, use a for loop to run this action 200 times and correct all of the   hrefs       on your page.
        <script type="text/javascript">
           for (var i=0;i<200;i++){
              //run document.getElementById() and .setAttribute, .createTextNode, etc. here
            }
        </script>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1so33q4z/36/

I would not recommend using document.write(); as mentioned in the other person's post, as this causes the page to work in a way the DOM is not meant to (writes serialized text). Especially if you need to correct 200 of them.  See this post [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)